# Why do Hindu Gods have parents if they have no masters?

Tags: gods, parents, contradiction

Why do Hindu Gods like Lord Krishna and Lord Ganesh have parents, even though Upanishads (see Shvetashvatara 6.9) say that god has no master, lord, or even parent?

Answer (score 1):

Lord Krishna don't have any parents. He is the eternal lord of Vaikhunta and Goloka. He just chose to descend on earth through Devaki -

> “Vishnu himself, worshipped by all the worlds, appeared in Devaki
> through Vasudeva, for the welfare of the world. He is of great fame,
> **the god without beginning and without end,** the lord and creator of the universe, unmanifest, without decay, **the brahman**, the chief,
> without any attributes, the great soul, **eternal**, nature, the lord
> who controls, the prime being, the **creator of the universe**, the
> source of the sattva quality, perennial, without deterioration,
> **infinite**, incapable of being moved, the god who is the supreme soul, Lord Narayana, the upholder, perpetual, the supreme **one
> without decay.** This prime being, with infinite wealth and the lord
> and grandfather of all beings, took his birth in the lineage of the
> Andhakas and the Vrishnis in order to increase righteousness in the
> world."

Adivansavatarana Parva, chapter 57, Mahabharata.

2. The reason Krishna became the son of Devaki was to fullfill a boon he had given to them in a previous birth -

> "Oh chaste lady! **In your previous birth in the age of Svāyambhuva
> Manu, you were Pṛśni and this sinless Vasudeva your husband, was then
> a Prajāpati named Sutapas.** When both of you were directed by god
> Brahmā to create progeny, you subdued all your senses and performed a
> very austere penance. Enduring in due course, all the inclemencies of
> the seasons such as rains, storms, solar rays, snow-fall and heat, you
> completely washed off the impurities of the mind by breathcontrol.
> **Subsisting on withered leaves and merely on air and actuated with the desire to obtain your cherished objects from me, you were
> determined to propitiate Me with a serene mind.** Thus rolled by
> twelve thousand divine years, while both of you, with your heart fixed
> on Me, were performing a very difficult and austere penance. Being
> continuously contemplated upon in the heart with faith, devotion and
> asceticism, I was highly pleased with you and manifested myself before
> you in this very form with a desire to fulfil your cherished objects,
> **Oh sinless one, When I, the foremost bestower of boons, told you to ask Me for a boon, the boon for having a son like Me was sought by
> you**. Though both of you had not tasted the conjugal and other
> pleasures of ordinary sensual objects and were childless, you did not
> seek for Emancipation (from the world) as you were deluded by My
> divine Māyā. When I disappeared from your view and you, having secured
> the boon of getting a son like Me and thus accomplishing your
> cherished desire, you indulged in enjoying sensual pleasures.
> **Finding that nobody else in this world is comparable to Me in goodness of nature, generosity and other virtues in this world, I
> Myself was born as your son and became known as Pṛśni-garbha**. **And
> again of you both (as Aditi and Kaśyapa) I was born of Aditi from
> Kaśyapa and was famous as Upendra and also as Vāmana due to shortness
> of stature.** **Now even in this third incarnation, I am verily born
> with that very form again of you both (who are former Aditi and
> Kaśyapa). In this way, my word has been kept, Oh pious lady."**

Chapter 3, 10th Skandha, Srimad Bhagavatam

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 types of Brahmana Nirguna and Saguna. And, There is only one Truth no second.

Svetasvatara Upanishad 3.7.:

> **Higher than this Personal Brahman is the infinite Supreme Brahman , who is concealed in all beings** according to their bodies , and who , **though remaining single , envelops the whole universe .** Knowing Him to be the Lord , one becomes immortal .

Svet. Upa 3.02 and Atharvasiras Upanishad 5.2.:

> “**Rudra is truly One; for the knowers of Brahman do not admit the existence of a second,** He is Ishana (Sun) and he alone rules all the worlds by His powers (as Indra). He dwells as the inner Self of every living being. After having created all the worlds (as Brahma), He, their Protector (as Vishnu), takes them back into Himself at the end of time (as Kala)."

Rig Veda 1.164.46.:

> They have styled Him as Indra, Mitra, Varuṇa, Agni, and he is the celestial, well-winged Garutmat, **for learned priests call the One Truth by many different names** as they speak of Agni, Yama, Mātariśvan.

Brahma Purana 2 (88) Bibek Debroy.:

> Shambhu alone is known by the names of Indra, Mitra, and Agni. **For the sake of those who are confused , Brahmanas speak of them in different ways.**

Atharva Veda 19:53:4.:

> “He (Kāla) surely did bring hither all the beings (worlds), he surely did encompass all the beings (worlds). **Being their father, he became their son;** there is, verily, no other force, higher than he”.

Shiva Purana 7:02:31:121-122.:

> “His (Shiva’s) works are said to be uncanny because he (alone) carries out creation, preservation and destruction. He is the one who cut brahma’s head. **He is the father of Brahma as well as his son. Similarly, He is the father of Vishnu as well as his son** and he is also the controller of Vishnu. He confers knowledge on these two – Brahma and Vishnu and always showers his grace (upon them)”.

Mahabharata. Harivamsa-Parva 2-74-34.:

> ”O the lord of lord! (Mahādeva) Myself (vishnu/krishna), brahma, kapila, ananta (sheSha), all the valiant sons of brahma who conquered over the internal enemies - **all are created from you. Hence you are the lord of all. Hence you, the lord of all, and are only one worthy of praise and worship.**

Swetasvatara Upanishad 4:10.:

> “Know then Prakriti (nature) is Mâyâ (art), and the Maheshwara the Mâyin (maker); **the whole world is filled with what are his members (forms)”.**

Rig Veda Khila. Shiva Sankalpa Shuktam 23.:

> The one that is recited soundless in all the Vedas, that supreme lord (Ishwara), **who is incorpeal (nirguna), non-pierceable self (atman),** may such my mind be of beautiful and divine resolves, filled with Auspicious Shiva-thoughts.-23.

Mandukya Upanishad 7.:

> "**The Fourth (Turiya)** is thought of as that which is not conscious of the internal world, nor conscious of the external world, nor conscious of both the worlds, nor dense with consciousness, nor simple consciousness, nor unconsciousness, which is unseen, actionless, incomprehensible, un-inferable, unthinkable, indescribable, **whose proof consists in the identity of the Self (in all states), in which all phenomena come to a cessation, and which is unchanging fourth (Turiya), peaceful (Shanta), auspicious Shiva, and non-dual. That is the Self; that is to be known.**

Avadhoota Gita of Sri Dattatreya 1.62.:

> 62 ) The world of form and the formless Void : Neither of these exists independently . In the One , there is neither separation nor union ; All is called no-no (not this-not that/neti-neti). Truly , **there is nothing but Shiva alone freed from all these differences.**

Dattatreya Upanishad.:

> **“Sarva Mantra Sarva Yantra Sarva Tantra Sarva Pallava Svaruupaya Iti Om Namah Shivaya. Om!”**

Varaha Upanishad.:

> 4.32. Shiva alone is Guru; Shiva alone is Vedas; Shiva alone is Lord; Shiva alone is I (Varaha Vishnu); **Shiva alone is All. There is none other than Shiva.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Burnol Prescribed for relief. ..